# How can i update an Input field in Child component from the Parent Component

Tags: reactjs

1. ```
   import React from 'react';
   import Child from './Child';

   class Parent extends React.Component{
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.state = {
               firstName: ""
           }
           this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
           this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
       }
       componentDidMount(){
           let fn = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fir"));
          if((localStorage.getItem("fir")!==undefined) && (localStorage.getItem("fir")!==null)){
              this.setState({
                  firstName: fn
              })
          }
       }

       handleChange(e){
           this.setState({
               [e.target.name] :[e.target.value]
           })
       }

       handleSubmit(){
           localStorage.setItem("fir", JSON.stringify(this.state.firstName));

           alert('submitted');
           console.log(this.state.firstName)
       }

       render(){
           return(
               <div>

                   <p> Parent</p>

                   <Child
                    firstName={this.state.firstName}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    />
                    {this.state.firstName}
               </div>
           )
       }
   }

   export default Parent;
   ```

2.

```
import React from "react";
class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: props.firstName
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p> Child</p>

        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}> submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Here i want to update an input field in Child component, But i'm stucked. can anyone help to update that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line in child

```
value={this.state.firstName}
```

to

```
value={this.props.firstName}
```

because *firstname* is being passed as a prop to child component

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value you need to update has `props` then use that props in the `value` of your input in child component. I can see you already passing the **firstName** has a `prop`, you just to change `state` to `props`

```
 <input
   type="text"
   name="firstName"
   value={this.props.firstName}
   onChange={this.props.handleChange}
 />
```